# Find records between two Quarters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find records between two-quarters of different years in SQL Server.

```
SELECT    ('Q'+cast(DATEPART(QUARTER,calldate) as varchar(3))+'-'+cast(YEAR(calldate) as varchar(4)))
period,providerid,volume as volume,type  
FROM  table V    
where DATEPART(QUARTER,calldate) between @Q1 and @Q2 and                             
datepart(year,calldate) in (@Y1,@Y2)  and providerid=@carrierID
```

Here Q1=4 and Q2=3 and @Y1=2014,@Y2=2016

```
 Now,I have only records from Q2-2016, So it should return available records      
 but I am getting blank rows.
 if I change the parameter like this 
 Here Q1=3 and Q2=4 and @Y1=2014,@Y2=2016 then i am getting records.
```

I want all records between these two-quarters like (Q3-2014 and Q2-2016).?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
where datename(year, calldate) + datename(quarter, calldate)
          between @Y1 + @Q1 and @Y2 + @Q2;
```

This assumes that the variables are actually strings.  You could also do this using numbers:

```
where datepart(year, calldate) * 10 + datename(quarter, calldate)
          between @Y1 * 10 + @Q1 and @Y2 * 10 + @Q2;
```

And, here is a way that would use indexes:

```
where calldate >= datefromparts(@Y1, @Q1*3 - 2, 1) and
      calldate < (case when @Q2 = 4
                       then datefromparts(@Y2 + 1, 1, 1)
                       else datefromparts(@Y2, @Q2*3 - 2 + 3, 1)
                  end)
```

Comment: year and quarter are type of tinyint

Comment: @Ramdeoangh . . . You have  a problem if they are `tinyint`, because that is not big enough to store a year (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: is your @year in full length, eg 2016, but not just 16?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I just converted it to varchar and it works. Thanks Man

Answer (score 1):

could try something like this

```
SELECT    
 ('Q'+cast(DATEPART(QUARTER,calldate) as varchar(3))+'-'+cast(YEAR(calldate) as varchar(4)))
period,providerid,volume as volume,type  
FROM  table V    
where DATEPART(QUARTER,calldate) + datepart(year,calldate) *4  between @Q1 + @Y1 * 4  and @Q2 + @Y2 * 4
```